# Replace Existing XMLTooling Library w/ Compiled Version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries, compilation

To remediate an Shibboleth SSO vulnerability (https://shibboleth.net/community/advisories/secadv_20180227.txt) I'm attempting to replace the existing libxmltooling7 library with a newer version (from 1.6.0-4 to 1.6.3).

I've successfully downloaded source, built dependencies, complied and verified the new library is installed in /usr/local...though dkpg -l is still showing the old version:

#
Output of dkpg -l | grep xmlt...

pi libxmltooling7:amd64 1.6.0-4switchaai1~trusty1 amd64 C++ XML parsing library with encryption support (runtime)
#

Am I missing a symbolic link somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before installing new one :

```
 dpkg -r --force-depends libxmltooling7
```

Comment: I appreciate the insight.  Unfortunately there are dependencies that would prohibit that action...

 libshibsp-plugins:amd64 depends on libxmltooling7...
 libshibsp7:amd64 depends on libxmltooling7...
 shibboleth-sp2-utils depends on libxmltooling7...
 libsaml9:amd64 depends on libxmltooling7...
 libapache2-mod-shib2 depends on libxmltooling7...

Comment: Check edited post, added `--force-depends`

Comment: Thank you Gilles...that allowed me, once I also executed dpkg -P --force-depends libxmltooling7, to remove the 1.6.0 version.  Now, even though my install 1.6.4 shows up in /usr/local/share/xml/xmltooling, dpkg -l isn't showing it.  Should it?